# adding numbers to same index in associative arrays plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to add a few consecutive numbers to the same index in an associative array in PL/SQL (Oracle).

I have defined the associative array as follows:

```
TYPE map_varchar IS TABLE OF NUMBER(30) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
l map_varchar;
```

I have an XML clob which I loop through and get a description(varchar) and amount(number) values. Say I have a description: 'A' and the following value 3,5,6

I want to map this as: 'A' > 14

```
 for r in (SELECT t.* 
  FROM XMLTABLE('*'
    PASSING xmltype(rec1.xml).
    EXTRACT('/ProductS/')
    COLUMNS description VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'some_xml_tag',
    amount NUMBER(30) PATH '_another_xml_tag') t)
LOOP
l(r.description) := l(r.description) + r.amount;
dbms_output.put_line('v_modifier_value_p: ' || r.description || ' amount: ' || r.saving);

END LOOP;
```

I'm trying the above but the line:

```
  l(r.description) := l(r.description) + r.amount;
```

is not working.

How can this be done in PLSQL?

Answer (score 1):

l(r.description) apparently needs to be initialized. So I added something like this:

```
if l.exists(r.description) then
    null;
  else
    l(r.description) := 0;
  end if;
```

this works now.

Answer (score 1):

replace the statement

```
l(r.description) := l(r.description) + r.amount;
```

with the following

```
if l.exists(r.description) then
  l(r.description) := l(r.description) + r.amount;
else
  l(r.description) := r.amount;
end if;
```